# converting a string into an array of double while removing trailing 0's

Tags: java

I need some guidance on a class project I am working on. I need to write a method that takes a string of numbers and turns them into an array of doubles while truncating any trailing 0's. I was able to take the string and convert it to an array of doubles but i am having issues figuring out how to remove the 0's from the end. Here is what i have so far

```
public double[] setCoeff(String coeff){
        String test = coeff;
        String[] doubleStrings = test.split(" "); // Splits each spaced double into a String array.
        double[] dubs = new double[doubleStrings.length]; // Creates the double array.
        for (int i = 0; i < dubs.length; i++) {
            dubs[i] = Double.parseDouble(doubleStrings[i]);//Parses the double for each string.
        }
        return dubs;
}//todo truncate trailing 0's
```

My first thought would be to loop through the split string finding the zeroes and making a new double array with the size of the split string minus the found 0's. The problem is i don't know how to differentiate between zeros  in the beginning / middle of the string vs the ones at the end. Any help or points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you convert your string to a double, insignificant zeroes after the decimal will already be removed for you.  How are you viewing the resulting doubles and determining they still have zeroes to remove?  If this doesn't seem to apply to your situation, list out some input and outputs that you are getting, and how the output needs to be different.

Comment: You first thought is right.  To count only the trailing zeros and not those at the start or in the middle, just start looking at the _end_ of the split array and work _backwards_, keeping count of the zeros, until you find a string that represents a non-zero number.  Then look no further.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, that way you broke it down really helped me make sense of it. Ill just make a Boolean flag and work back through the array until i find the last non 0 double then set the flag to true to exit the loop